# How to place a random pin within a country?

Tags: google-maps, location

Is there a way to place a pin at a random location within a country?

For instance, I like to place a pin at a random location within the Netherlands. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly as a part of Google Maps, but you can use an external service like : http://www.geomidpoint.com/random/ to locate a point within a country.

Sites like : http://www.mapcrunch.com/ use something like this.

Comment: I need to look into that, hope they got an API to play around with. I was kind of hoping Google Maps had a functionally for that =(

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can. 
Just get to the place you want to make a pin, and then clear your search, and then click the map (try clicking twice if nothing happens). It will put a gray dot. Then you can click the longitude and latitude coordinates in the little pop up box at the bottom. Once you click it, it will make it a red pin. You can save your pin, share it, etc.

Comment: Why you think this location will be random? Obviously author asks for programmatic solution (since we are on stackoverflow), no for clicking the map with bare hands.